# Preview icon design on iPhone/iPad (for amateurs)?

Tags: ios

our company is having an app made and our app developer is providing this service in-kind. They asked for icon files which I need to prepare for them.

Is there anyway I can preview what the app icon will look like, directly on my iPhone/iPad? I have Adobe Creative Suite (for preparing the graphics), but don't have any iOs developer tools.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mac, you can download XCode for free and preview your icon with the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I have ecountered this a few times. And there are a number of ways to do this.

1) Create the icon in png format and upload it to the HTML directory of your webserver. Name the icon 'apple-touch-icon.png'. Point safari on your phone to the url and hit the 'share' button and click the "add to home screen" button. Safari will add that link as an icon to your homescreen and use the "apple-touch-icon.png" as the icon for the link.

2) LiveView Screen caster is a great app for previewing in semi-real time your screen designs on the device. http://www.zambetti.com/projects/liveview/ If you create the icon in the right dimensions and you can preview it on device that way.  (My mistake, I actually thought there was a PC version of liveView, but appears there isn't)

Answer (score 0):

Try this iOS App, works great. It connects to your Photoshop, mirrors Photoshop's canvas onto your iOS device.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photoshop-display/id489161163

Answer (score 0):

I'd just send my icon files (pngs for example) to my iPad via e-mail or Dropbox. :)

Comment: think you missed the point on this one. the OP wants to see what his icon looks like after apple has applied their "love" to turn it into an app button.

Answer (score -1):

I made a tool that lets you upload an icon and it will text you a link that you can add to your home screen and preview the icon.

https://fredandrandall.com/iconpreview

Comment: The tool is working fine for me. What browser were you using?

Comment: I looked more closely at the error. Looks like you need to catch `Services_Twilio_RestException` when a phone # the API doesn't like is provided. I left my country code off the beginning of the # and it throws the above exception with a `To number: +MY_NUMBER_HERE, is not a mobile number` message. It works with the country code added. I'm happy to remove my down-vote, but can only do so after an edit is made to your answer.